# Rails: Sign in Users with just an email using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise

Here is my situation.  I am letting users to sign up in a landing page so that when the page is launched we can contact them. They are just entering their email.

What I am looking for is to automatically sign the user in, after he signs up because I want to be able to know if the just signed up User clicks on a button that is shown right away his sign up is finished.

How could I make it so that I know the email of the user who signed up? Where should I store this so that with a Javascript listener I am able to listen for a click and send that email back to the server?

Thanks

Comment: can not figure out what you need exactly but
if you want user to be signed_in after sign up automatically you can do it in the sign up method 
 **current_user = user** and redirect to his home page

Comment: The problem is about they are not setting the password.